# Taylor series near $0$ for $(1+x)^{\large\frac{\ln x}x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I want to find the Taylor series of $(1+x)^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}$.
I have tried to write it down as $e^{\frac{\ln x \ln{1+x}}{x}}$ but it didn't work. Also I tried to use $(1+x)^n =1+nx+n(n-1)x^2 /2$ but didn't work too.

Comment: What do you mean 'didn't work'?

Comment: @Farzin Is it a Taylor expansion near $0$?

Comment: Note that $\ln x$ has an essential singularity at $0$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yes,It is a Taylor expansion near 0.@Hagen von Eitzen can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $ x \to 0^+$.

One may use the classic Taylor expansion:
$$
\frac{\ln (1+x)}x=1-\frac{x}2+\frac{x^2}3+O(x^3)
$$ giving
$$
\ln x\:\frac{\ln (1+x)}x=\ln x-\frac{x\ln x}2+\frac{x^2\ln x}3+O(x^3\ln x)
$$ and writing
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{\large\frac{\ln x}x}&=e^{\large \:\ln x\:\frac{\ln (1+x)}x}
\end{align}
$$ leads to

> $$
> \begin{align}
> (1+x)^{\large\frac{\ln x}x}&=x-\frac{x^2 \ln x}{2} +O(x^3 \ln^2 x)
> \end{align}
> $$

where we have used that $x^p \ln^q x \to 0$ ($p>0,q>0$) as $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your last step.How did you reached this:$x-x^2 lnx/2 $ using this:$e^(lnx - xlnx/2 )$

Comment: @Farzin You may write $$\displaystyle e^{\ln x -\frac{x\ln x}2}=e^{\ln x}\times e^{-\frac{x\ln x}2}=x \times \left(1-\frac{x\ln x}2+O(x^2\ln x)\right)$$ Thanks.